# ADB not seeing devices on Debian 8.2

Tags: android, android-studio, debian, adb, udev

After moving from Windows to Debian I've encountered big problem. I can't run any of my apps developed in Android Studio. "Device Chooser" doesn't see any of my devices (LG G2 and LG G4), "adb devices" also gives no results:

adb devices:

```
nomader@ideapad:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

But phone is clearly connected:

lsusb:

```
nomader@ideapad:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 04f2:b2f1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 09da:9090 A4 Tech Co., Ltd XL-750BK Laser Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1004:633e LG Electronics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I added rule to /etc/udev/rules.d

51-android.rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

and edited adb_usb.ini:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x1004
```

But none of this worked and I'm still not able to detect my devices.

Any ideas?

edit: on Windows everything was working

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html

Comment: Almost none of it works for me. I've only found Interface Descriptor in `lsusb -v` that matches one in article, but I already added 0x1004 to adb_usb.ini and `~$ find -L /sys/bus/usb/devices -maxdepth 2 -path "*/modalias" -printf "%h\t" -exec cat {} \; | \
awk -F: '/icFFisc42ip0/ {print $1}' | xargs -i cat {}/idVendor | awk '{print"0x"$1}' ` doesn't give any output. My hardware is working, because on Windows everything is working perfectly.

Comment: forget `adb_usb.ini`. it's no longer needed (since platform-tools v23). but no output from `find -L /sys/bus/usb/devices -maxdepth 2 -path "*/modalias" -printf "%h\t" -exec cat {} \; | grep 'icFFisc42ip01'` mean that `USB Debugging` is not on (or working properly) on your device.

Comment: Is there possibility that USB Debugging is not working properly on my devices if on Windows everything works? Is there  any setting that I can change to make this work on Debian?

Comment: I've found solution. I was pretty desperate, so I started switching settings on my phones and it turned out that changing USB Connection from MTP to PTP fixes this problem.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution. I was pretty desperate, so I started switching settings on my phones and it turned out that changing USB Connection from MTP to PTP fixes this problem.

Answer (score -2):

You should

a) restart `udev` after editing `/etc/udev/rules.d/*` files

```
$ sudo service udev restart
```

b) replug your device after restarting `udev` - just plug it off and in again.

Also, you must install 32-bit libs if you run 64-bit OS.

Comment: I'm restarting my computer after every change in rules and it still doesn't work. Which libs do you mean?

Comment: Both Andrey's suggestions are irrelevant. It is not a permissions issue (so `udev` is not going to help). And since `adb devices` printed `List of devices attached` line - you already have all the libraries you need for `adb` to work.